# How to make autocomplete textbox in excel cell in VSTO C# add in

Tags: c#, excel, vsto, add-in

I am now developing Excel VSTO add in, and I am newbie in addin development. I Found that I can Add hyperlink control to Cell directly and can handle event on it as follow.

```
worksheet.Hyperlinks.Add(
       rangeToHoldHyperlink,
       string.Empty,
       hyperlinkTargetAddress,
       "Tip",
        "label");
```

What I want to do is to add automplete text box (show autocomplete text on key down event) in specified cells as following picture.
[image: Sample Photo]

I know about creating dropdown cell by  setting data validation list from c#. But I don't want to use this because it doesn't show on key down event and dropdown list data is limitted. And I can't find related solution from google, Please help me if anybody has already done this snippet.
Thanks alot.

Comment: http://www.ozgrid.com/forum/showthread.php?t=144438 may help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose that you can add a NameRange control to this cell. It has several events, like Change. You can  add some functions to this event. 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.tools.excel.namedrange.aspx
I hope it works.